# broken dependencies: intltool

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, apt-get

I got a raspberry pi 3B and I'm working with it since two days. While trying to get my bluetooth headset working I stuck in a problem while installing intltool package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install intltool
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
intltool : Depends: libxml-parser-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

With

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get

```
0 updated, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not updated.
```

and

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and

```
sudo apt-get -f check
```

had no success.
Additionally

```
sudo sh -c "apt-get update;apt-get dist-upgrade;apt-get autoremove;apt-get autoclean"
```

is helping neither.

Comment: Please add the output of `grep -IRH '^deb ' /etc/apt/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the Os you are using the problem could be that you don't have the correct repositories enabled. Despite that, what you can certainly do to install intltool is the following:

- Download the package from [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/libxml-parser-perl)
- Install the `.deb` file.
- Run `sudo apt-get install intltool` again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am getting the following error: 
`Sudo dpkg -i intltool_0.50.2-2_all.deb`:
Dpkg: dependency problems of this configuration of intltool:
Intltool depends on libxml-parser-perl; But:
Libxml-parser-perl package is not installed.

Dpkg: Error processing package intltool (--install):
Dependency problems - remains unconfigured
Triggering man-db (2.7.0.2-5) processing ...
Errors occurred while editing:
intltool`

Comment: Sorry I forgot: I am using the OS Jessie

Comment: Do You habe and further instructions?